# Eclipse RCP: Add image to list

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to add images to the items in a list in Eclipse RCP. I provide a custom LabelProvider which looks like:

```
package com.puresol;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;

public class MyListLabelProvider extends LabelProvider {

    private final Image folderImage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
        .getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FOLDER);

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        folderImage.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        return element.toString();
    }

    @Override
        public Image getImage(Object element) {
        return folderImage;
    }
}
```

I add this label provider by:

```
listViewer.setLabelProvider(new MyListLabelProvider());
```

I do get the correct text, but no image. I am sure my label provider is used due to debugging the code and I can change the provided label text, too. I only do not see an image. The image is loaded and non-null.

What do I need to switch on to get the label shown? What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the `ListViewer` is capable of displaying images. Try to switch to a single-column `TableViewer` and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, indeed it helps. Why should the ListViewer not be able to show images? Is there a reason practical reason for that? I changed List to Table and ListViewer to TableViewer. Everything else stayed the same...

Comment: The `ListViewer` is quite limited in functionality. I think it may be because it uses more native widgets from the OS, while the `TableViewer` (or I `Table` rather) is a more complete reimplementation. But that is just my theory...